# Quality of weighted least square fit

Tags: least-squares, goodness-of-fit, wls

I fitted a linear regression with heteroscedescity using weighted least square method. How do I evaluate the quality of my fitting? I’m thinking by the p-value of slope/intercept. Or maybe because I minimized the cost function and that process already does the talking?

Comment: A p-value of a slope never measures the quality of a fit, at least not in any usual sense of "quality."  Could you elaborate on what you mean by "quality"?

Comment: @whuber thats the question I would like to ask. How do I define the quality of the fit?

Answer (score 3):

A simple function to calculate R squared from a weighted LS fit would be

```
get_r2_ss <- function(y, y_pred, w) {
  # Calculate R2 using the Sum of Squares method
  # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions
  ss_residual = sum(w * (y - y_pred) ^ 2)
  ss_total = sum(w * (y - weighted.mean(y, w)) ^ 2)
  return(1 - ss_residual / ss_total)
}
```

but if you use a weighted lm fit you will also simply get it using

```
summary(lm(y~x, weights=weights))$r.squared
```

If you want to look at the quality of the fit taking into account the nr of parameters that were fit then you can of course also use adjusted R squared

```
summary(lm(y~x, weights=weights))$adj.r.squared
```

or AIC or BIC, using

```
AIC(lm(y~x, weights=weights)) or BIC(lm(y~x, weights=weights))
```